# Store properties of C# class in different tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to develop an application to collect, edit and save member data of our football club. I want to save the data into a database using Microsoft Entity Framework.

I created a class to represent a `Member` containing information like name, address and memberships (e.g. active member, inactive member, former member, etc.)

Memberships are saved in a list in the `Member` class.

What I want to do: I want to save the `Member` using Entity Framework to store member data in a SQL table `Member`. The list with `Memberships` should automatically be saved in an other table `Memberships`. When I load a `Member` from the database, it should automatically load its `Memberships` as well.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Then there should be a relation between `Member` and `MemberShips`, 1:1 or 1:N

Comment: @Aria The relation should be 1:N

Comment: So read [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) to know more about defining you `Member` and `MemberShips` relation.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define relation between Member and Membership as 1:M relation 
if it is defined so you can retrive Memberships list using include method

```
using (var context = new DBNameContext()) 
{ 

    // Load one member and its related Memberships 
    var member1 = context.Members 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "Test") 
                        .Include(b => b.Memberships) 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

you can check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) it will help alos